# Why are binary safe strings such a big deal in redis? Don't most languages provide binary safe strings by default?

Tags: redis

I was reading the redis protocol specification, and the fact the redis has binary safe strings was a major point, why is this such a big deal ? Am i missing something ?

Comment: Ask all those poor folk who have to base64-encode their binary data in JSON, or SOAP, or XML... thereby making it slower and 30% bigger.

Comment: @MarkSetchell could you elaborate ? i am new to this stuff, so i don't understand.

Comment: Some protocols/formats do not allow binary data - generally because the binary data may include some bytes that they already use to delimit ends of lines, words or streams and if they allowed binary data they might get confused by it. JSON and XML are examples of such things. So, if you want to transmit binary data in JSON or XML, you normally end up base64-encoding it and just using 64 human-readable ASCII characters instead of binary data. Have a read here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 When you do that, it takes time and the data needs more network bandwidth and storage space.